# 2 different access tables with 2 field in common (RAM/Machine Name) and trying to merge RAM info

Tags: ms-access

Hi I have 2 tables in access from different reports referring to machine names and specs. Unfortunately both tables have numerous records where RAM is empty and would like to merge both tables to a new table to minimise the amount of records that do not specify the amount of RAM for a machine record.
Both tables are very different but both contain machine names and RAM.

Comment: so what records do you want in the new table? just the name and the ram?
And only the ones where ram is not empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merg the tables using `UNION`

Table 1 (Machine1):

[image]

Table 2 (Machine2):

[image]

Then you can create a view:

```
SELECT Machine1.MachineName, CStr(Machine1.RAM)
FROM Machine1
WHERE Machine1.RAM <> null

UNION 

SELECT Machine2.MachineName, CStr(Machine2.RAM)
FROM  Machine2
WHERE Machine2.RAM <> null;
```

[image]

I hope this helps, otherwise, please try to clarify your problem a bit more, maybe give some example data.
See [this link](https://www.thoughtco.com/view-edit-sql-in-microsoft-access-1019934) for closer information about edit the SQL directly in access.

Comment: I believe this to be 1 table RAM is  this format 7.9 and the other table has RAM as 8GB not sure how to get round this format issue

Comment: so you have "GB" in one, and decimal numbers in the other? What are the types of the fields?

Comment: see my update to the sql query, this casts the two RAM columns as string and then check for null.